# Error installing phpMyAdmin - openssl10 required

Tags: linux, openssl, redhat

I am trying to install phpMyAdmin on my REHL 6 server. I have installed openssl10 with the command; `yum install openssl10`

I installed it from the ius repo.

However, I am getting an error about missing dependencies when installing phpMyAdmin;

```
Error: Package: php-cli-5.4.26-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-5.4.26-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-recode-5.4.26-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: librecode.so.0()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

I'm pretty new to Linux, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

i don't know linux much either but you don't have to do yum install anything , package is there in your php binary itself , you just have to enable it from php.ini.

if in case you are trying to install phpmyadmin using "YUM" , then i don't know how it work ,mostly i just download phpmyadmin and place it on the web app directory of the server.

Answer (score 0):

OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC is provided by the stock openssl libraries.

```
objdump -p /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10

Version definitions:
1 0x01 0x0af47420 libcrypto.so.10
2 0x00 0x0af47420 libcrypto.so.10
3 0x00 0x066a2b21 OPENSSL_1.0.1
4 0x00 0x02b21533 OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC
```

so that could mean you do not use the original libraries. Maybe ptudor's? https://www.ptudor.net/linux/openssl/

He drops openssl-1.0.1e/version.map.fips-ec entirely but do not want to include the version export. https://github.com/ptudor/centos6-openssl/issues/4

If so you can still fix it by rebuilding those ptudor library this way

```
--- openssl-1.0.1e-version.patch        2014-06-06 11:52:55.772046103 +0200
+++ new_openssl-1.0.1e-version.patch    2014-06-06 11:52:40.854045438 +0200
@@ -61,4 +61,12 @@
 +          _original*;
 +          _current*;
 +};
++OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC {
++    global:
++           EC*;
++};
```

Or else you can also rebuild the package that cannot be install now and link that to your custom openssl library.